# Is there something like a 'registry' concept to check for available events to subscribe to with when in a pubsub environment?

Tags: javascript, events, publish-subscribe

Maybe this is a contradictio in terminis, but I'm wondering if there is such a thing as a registry concept which contains all available events to subscribe to when working in a pubsub environment.

**Context of use**

Imagine you are a widget being pulled in by a website. This website publishes certain events that you can subscribe to. Only, you don't know on forehand which events are available in that site.

I imagine that you can publish a standard event to the site, which then returns a list of all available events for subscription on that site.

With that information you can then decide to subscribe to specific events.

**My Questions**

- Do you know of any such concept in use?
- Is this even feasible?
- Would there be any security concerns?

Thanks in advance! :)

Rein

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I have found what I was looking for in a similar but different solution: 'signals'

As described by the library editor ([js-signals](http://millermedeiros.github.io/js-signals/)) himself:

> A Signal is similar to an Event Emitter/Dispatcher or a Pub/Sub system, the main difference is that each event type has it's own controller and doesn't rely on strings to broadcast/subscribe to events.

Basically the feature that describes what I was after in PubSub is the first bullet under the header 'Advatages':

- Doesn't rely on strings for subscribing/publishing to a event type:

  - Trying to dispatch or listen to an event type that doesn't exist throws errors instead of failing silently which helps to identify errors early.

I haven't worked with it yet, but it seems to answer my question.